# What are your up/downvote ethics?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes, polling, ethics

- I'm upvoting questions if I think they can be useful (maybe I need an answer later on)
- also on answers, or things I know they're correct
- I don't upvote to answers on the same question when I already gave a answer (competition)
- I downvote only on glaring misleading answers and hope the upvotes will decide.

Somtime I think somthing is cool or not but rather exeptions.

Do you think this is balanced?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-should-i-upvote-a-question and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for similar answers to my issue, I hope to find another opinions.

Comment: Not voting for answers (good or bad) in competition with your own? For shame. Or do you not trust your ow judgment?

Answer (score 1):

Well I basically follow these two rules:

- If it makes me happier than I was
  before I read it **upvote**.
- If it makes
  me sadder than I was before I read it
  **downvote**.

Comment: Sounds like criteria for Joke Overflow.

Comment: That is basically what I go by.  If it is a good answer, it makes me happy.  If it is a bad answer it makes me sad.