# What should I consider when I invite colleagues to SE?

Tags: discussion, ethics

Over the last few days I shared some things that I learned at work on the SE network in Q&A-style. To me, that seemed better than having the knowledge lost forever in various "internal reports", or worse, labbook entries. When I told my colleagues about it, they seemed intrigued and wanted to try it out as well. We work at a publicly funded research institute, so sharing our knowledge here under a CC-SA license seems like a good "fit" to the overall effort.

Since we have similar interests, we will probably end up voting and working on the same sections and even questions on SE. When we are at work, we will also share the same IP-address.

Before inviting more colleagues, I am wondering about two things:

1. Should I worry that I will be accused of creating an army of sockpuppets? Due to the overlap in interests and IP-address, this could (and probbly should!) come up.
2. At what point is a subgroup of people that know each other "gaming the system"? It is not unlikely that we will be discussing an issue together until one of us figures it out and shares the solution Q&A style. The 3-4 people that were involved in the discussion then have a [valid reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141/226112) to upvote. Is this considered ethical?

Comment: There is an exact duplicate of that question somewhere...

Comment: Until someone can find a dupe, the short answer is don't vote on each other's questions at the very least, and recognize that some of your votes may be reversed if you all vote on a single post, but if you really aren't abusing anything and aren't voting for each other then I imagine you won't look like a single person to a mod and thus won't bet suspended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I worry that I will be accused of creating an army of sockpuppets? Due to the overlap in interests and IP-address, this could (and probbly should!) come up.

It's common for groups of people from the same company or university to share an IP address.  This alone won't raise any suspicion.  Once accounts from the same IP address start voting for each other though, we do start looking your way.

> At what point is a subgroup of people that know each other "gaming the system"?

We can't tell you at exactly what point, because then people will use that information to game the system.  If accounts are created that seem to only exist to upvote each other, we'll send out warnings, and in some cases suspend and delete accounts.  If you and your colleagues are using the site and voting normally, you won't have any reason to fear.

---

For a very general rule of thumb, follow tags (topics) that you're interested in, not just individual users.