# Meta Stack Overflow questions which didn't get answers with positive scores

Tags: discussion, meta

At some moment I asked this question:
[Incentives for answering questions in unpopular (small) tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197015/incentives-for-answering-questions-in-unpopular-small-tags)

It's still near and dear to my heart and based on reasonable amount of upvotes, there are people who think along the same lines with me.

However, this question only got two answers which were both downvoted.

What should I do with questions like that? Should I try to bump them (by editing them) or should I let me go (taking into account that they won't super highly up voted).

BTW. I understand that there will be [Observer effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_%28physics%29) here. As soon as I mentioned that post, there will be some influx of comments, answers. However, I want to understand broader picture here - what people do with such type of questions/suggestions.

Comment: Put a bounty on it?

Comment: Same as you do on Stack Overflow.  Doesn't make much different if it's old, or not answered well, or on meta, etc.