# Buying a beer for good answers

Tags: feature-request

I am really thankful for all the help I received from SO community. Recently I came across an answer that saved me considerable amount of time. I upvoted and thanked as a comment but this doesn't feel like the answer's worth to me. Hence If there was a button, besides upvoting, like "Buy a Beer" to just buy a beer where by clicking I could thank by just giving 2 or 3 $, up to 5 I guess just to show appreciation. I once saw an answer with 710 upvotes and  I'm sure at least 1 person would have had the luxury to thank by buying a beer. I am aware SO is a thought exchange community free of monetary issues but is this not possible?

Comment: There are plenty of sites on the internet trying to solve that exact problem; this is not something SE sites need to solve though.

Comment: I don't see this as a problem but could you explain why not?

Comment: because there is such a thing as scope creep? Next someone will want to send a donation to their favourite answerer, then it's a whole car. Contact the person directly instead if they shared contact info. The focus of the site is the questions and their answers, and we have voting to signal quality. That's plenty.

Comment: I think this question from the list at the right surprisingly covers this very well considering the name: [Buy a Beer Badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29563/buy-a-beer-badge?rq=1)

Comment: Having a max limit of 5$ per answer (maybe additional 5 beers per day) limits such a thing. Besides, If the answer is worth a car and/or if someone has such luxury and they do want to send more why be against it?

Comment: @animuson That one talks about giving rep.

Comment: Because it's simply not what this site does. It does not do monetary rewards. Not after the fact and not as an incentive to answer either. It's all fake points and not-so-shiny badges.

Comment: @mechanicum: Read Jon Skeet's answer. There are ways you can "give someone money" without the need for a silly button here on the site.

Comment: Remember some of us are minors...

Comment: I don't drink beer.

Comment: Beer is a common slang thing for this. It can be buy a Taco, buy a burger whatever you want. Doesn't matter right now though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can:

- Check the user's profile to see if he left any contact info. If he did, contact him directly and offer the purchase of said beer (particularly if you will be locationally near one another in the immediate future)
- Start a bounty on the question he answered and give it to that answer, there is even a bounty reason "Great Answer". For many people on Stack Overflow 500 rep points taste better than any beer.

Comment: "Suggest that bear". Polar, grizzly, brown, or black? You send that to that nasty downvoter, right? :-P

Comment: @Martijn users leaving contact information should see it coming. ;)

Comment: Buying a bear is a bit out of my paycheck range. But the contact suggestion is ok I guess even if a little weird. "Hey random stranger, thanks for the answer, give me your bank account details so I can buy you a beer"

Comment: @mechanicum not really, I was thinking more of "Hello, I saw your answer [link here] and was very impressed. If you ever come by near [place here] feel free to let me know so I can buy you a beer". I, for one, will be flattered by such a message. :-)